# Appending code to the contents of an svg in an <object>

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an `<object>` that holds an svg file. I want to be able to add animations to it via javascript / jQuery, because the values that I would like to animate are not selectable via CSS transistions (specifically, the `r` value of `<circles>`. I would love to be proven wrong, though!). Here's what I'm trying to use:

```
//create the object to hold the svg
$(selProject).append('<object id="circleCont" data="imgs/circles-01.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>')
    var a = document.getElementById("circleCont");
    a.addEventListener("load",function(){
          var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of .svg
          var circ = svgDoc.getElementsByClassName('circ');
          $(circ[0]).append('<animate attributeName="r" from="0.01" to="300" dur="0.2" begin="0s" fill="freeze"/>');
    },false);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. What is the better method to handle this?

Comment: I don't find your question very clear : Is it really necessary to load your svg image from a file (imgs/circles-01.svg) ? -eg a circle could be generated in svg with javascript- What animation are you trying to apply to your svg image ?

Comment: @Harijoe if you're referring to running the svg inline, I technically could, but I've been having difficulty controlling the viewport of the svg when run inline (as it needs to be dynamically resizing. Putting the svg in an `<object>` has the advantage of being much easier to control the size of.

Comment: Actually I was suggesting to use a library such as [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) to generate your svg figures. It's actually really easy to animate them if done this way.